# Binding with ListView SelectedItem vs TextCell Command

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I have a scenario where I need to take the value of a selected TextCell and use it to update a Label outside of the ListView. I notice that ListView has a SelectedItem property and the TextCell has a Command property. What is the difference between these?

As a more general design question (I am using Xamarin MVVM), how should I go about doing the update? Currently I was thinking of using the ListView SelectedItem property and binding it (Two-Way) with my VM. Then in the Setter I would update the VM propery that the label is bounded to.... Problem is that I have an async task that I need to do as it will translate the TextCell value to what I need the Label value to be.... How should I do this?

I have seen mentions of behaviors but that seems to be more for the UI (not logic). I also played with the idea of using Task.Run for getting around the async issue in the setter but it is quite obvious that async items are not meant for setters. Also I thought about using the MessagingCenter but that seems to be for VM -> VM. TextCell command seems appropriate but have read to use SelectedItems instead.

View:

```
<ListView x:Name="ResultsList"
                          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDestinationItem,
                                                 Mode=TwoWay}">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextCell Text="{Binding Description}" Detail="{Binding Place_ID}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
<Label Text="{Binding Current.Destination}"/>
```

And for the VM:

```
public AutoCompletePrediction SelectedDestinationItem
    {
        get => _selectedDestinationItem;
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _selectedDestinationItem, value, "SelectedDestinationItem");
            if (_selectedDestinationItem == null) return;
            //not valid
            var place = await Places.GetPlace(_selectedDestinationItem.Place_ID, Constants.PlacesApiKey); 
            Current.Destination = place;
            SelectedDestinationItem = null;


        }
    }

    private AutoCompletePrediction _selectedDestinationItem;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You Bind your Label to a Property of you VM lets say Text
- You Bind the SelectedItem of the ListView to a Property of your VM let's call it SelectedItem
- In the setter of SelectedItem you call a Task.Run(() => DoWork(value)) to do your work or get your translation
- At the End of your work you set the Property Text
- The Property Setter of Text should call a PropertyChanged
- That's it

Sample VM:

```
public class MyViewModel : ViewModelBase {
    private string _text;
    public string Text {
        get => _text;
        set {
            _text = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private YourItemType _selectedItem;
    public YourItemType SelectedItem {
        get => _selectedItem;
        set {
            _selectedItem = value;
            Task.Run(() => GetValue(value));
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private readonly object _lockObject = new object();
    private void GetValue(YourItemType item){
        if(item == null) {
           Text = "invalid";
           return;
        }  

        //avoid entering twice here
        lock(_lockObject) {
            //Do your work here - it's in the background already
            Text = resultOfWork;
        }
    }
}
```

OnPropertyChanged() is the Implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged. Something like:

```
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChangedByName(string propertyName) {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public void RefreshView() {
        foreach (var propertyInfo in GetType().GetRuntimeProperties()) {
            OnPropertyChangedByName(propertyInfo.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So the Task.Run is fine in the setter... Fair enough. Thank you.

Comment: Is the purpose of Task.Run is to put it on a different thread other than the UI? I've always only used it with async methods.